# jqgrid and view record, how to set the width

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I set the width of the default view from the grid.
The default is 300px but I can't find any documentation on how to change it.
I could find info on changing the width of the default edit but not the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The place of the documentation is [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties1). You can specify the `width` in the parameters of `viewGridRow` method. You call the method directly like here

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    $(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', id, {width: 500});
}
```

or you can use "View" icon in the navigator bar:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    {add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, view: true},
    {/*edit options*/}, {/*add options*/}, {/*del options*/}, {/*search options*/},
    {width: 500});
```

Comment: Oleg, I'm able to set the width using your first example, but not the second, using the exact same format of your example. This is jqGrid 4.3.1. I ended up setting a css rule instead.

Comment: @earachefl: Thanks, you are right. I forgot to include Search parameters (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)). I fixed the code. I find better to change the defaults `$.expand($.jgrid.search, {width: 500});` and then skip all the last parameters of `navGrid`.

Comment: @Oleg I cant change the width of view icon. How to do, I am using jqgrid4.5.4.  please help me how to set width and label size of the viewGridrow

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: There are many ways to implement the requirements. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13865495/315935), [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854864/315935) and many other.

Comment: Thank you @Oleg: sorry for the mistake of my comment... My query is the width could not be change in view form. How to handle the size of the form and how to make the space between label and value in the view form.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: Sorry, but I still don't understand your question. It's better if you post new question where you will describe and show (with screenshort) why the standard [View options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties1) can't solve your problem.

Comment: @Oleg this is my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/22498523/2806972 please review this post thank you for your comments.