# jqGrid Pager Area - Using Font Awesome Icons

Tags: jqgrid, font-awesome

I would like to use Font Awesome icons:

```
<i class="icon-edit"></i>
```

in the jqGrid pager area instead of the physical images by default.

```
.navButtonAdd('#vw_ComplaintSearchGridPager', { caption: '', buttonicon: 'ui-icon-disk', title: 'Save Grid Settings', onClickButton: function () { $(this).SaveGridSetting(); } })
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's very interesting question! I never used [Font Awesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) before, but it seems very interesting project.

jqGrid has currently no direct support of Font Awesome icons, but I prepared [**the simple demo**](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FortAwesome/FortAwesome.htm) which shows how to replace the standard jQuery UI navigator icons with the corresponding icons from Font Awesome.

One can see mostly clear the difference to the original navigator icons after zoom of the page. I included below the navigator displayed with zoom 400%:

The original navigator using jQuery UI icons

[image]

The navigator with Font Awesome icons:

[image]

The code which I used is very simple. Instead of usage

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {view: true});
```

I used

```js
$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", {editicon: "icon-pencil",
    addicon: "icon-plus", delicon: "icon-trash", searchicon: "icon-search",
    refreshicon: "icon-refresh", viewicon: "icon-file",view: true});

$("#pager .navtable .ui-pg-div>span").removeClass("ui-icon");
```

I added the CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div>span { margin: 0 5px; font-size: 12px; }
```

I think it's possible to replace more jQuery UI icons to Font Awesome icons, but it's not very simple. I will think about the problem more and will contact the developer of jqGrid (Tony Tomov) to consider to make jqGrid more friendly to Font Awesome icons, so that it could be possible very simple switch to Font Awesome icons.

**UPDATED**: I added the code which allows top replace more icons from the pager:

```js
var $pager = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".ui-pg-table");
$pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-first")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first")
    .addClass("icon-step-backward");
$pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-prev")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev")
    .addClass("icon-backward");
$pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-next")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next")
    .addClass("icon-forward");
$pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-end")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end")
    .addClass("icon-step-forward");
```

As the result one get the following pager:

[image]

instead of

[image]

**UPDATED 2**: The code for changing minimizing icon looks a little completer. One should first change the icon initially

```js
$grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid")
    .find(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar>.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close>.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n")
    .addClass("icon-circle-arrow-down");
```

and then change it after every click on the icon:

```js
onHeaderClick: function (gridstate) {
    if (gridstate === "visible") {
        $(this.grid.cDiv).find(">.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close>span")
            .removeClass("icon-circle-arrow-up ui-icon-circle-triangle-n")
            .addClass("icon-circle-arrow-down");
    } else if (gridstate === "hidden") {
        $(this.grid.cDiv).find(">.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close>span")
            .removeClass("icon-circle-arrow-down ui-icon-circle-triangle-s")
            .addClass("icon-circle-arrow-up");
    }
}
```

Additionally one need to add the CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close>span { margin: 0 3px; font-size: 16px; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close { text-decoration: none; }
```

To fix the sorting icons I used the code

```js
var $sortables = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid")
    .find(".ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-jqgrid-labels .ui-jqgrid-sortable span.s-ico");
$sortables.find(">span.ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s")
    .addClass("icon-sort-down");
$sortables.find(">span.ui-icon-triangle-1-n")
    .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n")
    .addClass("icon-sort-up");
```

and the CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-asc { height: auto; margin-top: 0; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-asc, .ui-jqgrid .ui-icon-desc {
    height: auto; margin-top: 0; margin-left: 5px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .s-ico>.ui-state-disabled, .s-ico>.ui-state-disabled { padding: 0; }
```

As the result one will get the following:

[image]

**UPDATED 3**: In [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FortAwesome/FortAwesome1.htm) one can find more full replacement of jQuery UI icons to Font Awesome icons.

**UPDATED 4**: [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/315935) provides solution for Font Awesome version 4.x.

Comment: @PaulBrown: You are welcome! I posted [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/support-of-font-awesome-icons-in-jqgrid/#p27916) to trirand.

Comment: @PaulBrown: In **UPDATED 3** part of my answer I added more full replacement of jQuery UI icons to Font Awesome icons.

Answer (score 2):

Figured I would put a CSS alternative answer for those interested.  One of our developers implemented a JS option, which did functionally work, however, there was a delay before it rendered correctly (not ideal).

We used font-awesome icons for our paging options, and here is how we implemented it.

Found the four classes that jqGrid was using for the paging icons we desired to customize and created the following css to apply base font awesome styles

```
.ui-icon-seek-next, .ui-icon-seek-prev, .ui-icon-seek-end, .ui-icon-seek-first
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
```

Then it is simply a matter of grabbing the `content` from font-family icon and using them as your own.

```
.ui-icon-seek-next:before
{
    content: "\f105";
}
.ui-icon-seek-prev:before
{
    content: "\f104";
}
.ui-icon-seek-end:before
{
    content: "\f101";
}
.ui-icon-seek-first:before
{
    content: "\f100";
}
```

So the entire CSS together looks like this

```
.ui-icon-seek-next, .ui-icon-seek-prev, .ui-icon-seek-end, .ui-icon-seek-first
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
.ui-icon-seek-next:before
{
    content: "\f105";
}
.ui-icon-seek-prev:before
{
    content: "\f104";
}
.ui-icon-seek-end:before
{
    content: "\f101";
}
.ui-icon-seek-first:before
{
    content: "\f100";
}
```

And the output on our grid without JS and without delay
[image]

Answer (score 1):

By looking at answer from Oleg above, I did the following to simplify things.
**Additional CSS**

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager .ui-pg-div>span.fntawsm { margin: 0 5px; font-size: 12px; padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px;}
```

** padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px; is optional
And this only works with icons only with no caption ...

And then just start adding fontawesome icons in navButtonAdd like

```
caption:"", // important for above
title:"Give any",
buttonicon:"fntawsm icon-remove"
buttonicon:"fntawsm icon-eject icon-rotate-90"
```

etc .. You can use all extra functionality from font-awesome like icon-rotate-XX too.
Thisway i did`nt have to remove ui-icon class from spans.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired by @afreeland answer, I created a css available on github which allows you to convert your icons to Font-Awesome icons.

The performance advantage of this over the jquery method that @Oleg described is important in my opinion. 
It is also a very elegant solution in my opinion.

You are welcome to use it: https://github.com/guylando/ToAF

Note: you must give priority for this ToAF.css file styles over your other icons styles so that can be achieved for example by copying the css content into a  tag in your document.