# jqgrid change icons used by the pager

Tags: jqgrid

I need to change the forward (>, >|) and back (<, |<) pager icons used by jqgrid.  The icons I'd like to use are already contained within jquery ui file ui-icons_888888_256x240.png.  How do I accomplish this?

Update:

Based on the response here [jqGrid Pager Area - Using Font Awesome Icons, I've added the following code to my page, but the icons aren't changing.  I'm getting the pager, but I don't think I'm getting the icon span.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $pager = $("#" + pagerName);

var icon = $pager.find(".ui-icon>span.ui-icon-seek-first");
    icon.removeClass("ui-icon-seek-first");
    icon.addClass("ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w");

$pager.find(".ui-icon>span.ui-icon-seek-prev")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-seek-prev")
    .addClass("ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w");

$pager.find(".ui-icon>span.ui-icon-seek-next")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-seek-next")
    .addClass("ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e");

$pager.find(".ui-icon>span.ui-icon-seek-end")
    .removeClass("ui-icon-seek-end")
    .addClass("ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e");

</script>
```

Comment: it is not possible to change default jqgrid icons. Refer [themeroller](http://www.jqueryui.com/themeroller/#icons) for changing to another given icons.

Comment: @udaykiranpulipati I don't believe that's true.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862963/jqgrid-pager-area-using-font-awesome-icons?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I didn't realize is that any JavaScript code that overrides the buttons used by the jqgrid needs to be included in the JavaScript function that loads the jqgrid.  Below is the code I used:

```
  // Override default pager icons
  $grid = $("#" + listName);
  $pager = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".ui-pg-table");

  var icon = $pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-first");
      icon.removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first");
      icon.addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-w");

  $pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-prev")
      .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev")
      //.addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w")
      .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w")
      ;

  $pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-next")
      .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next")
      //.addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e")
        .addClass("ui-icon  ui-icon-triangle-1-e")
      ;

  $pager.find(".ui-pg-button>span.ui-icon-seek-end")
      .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end")
      .addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-e");
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** ok, in that case:

```
// First page: |<
$("#first_your-pagerID span").removeClass("ui-icon-seek-first");
$("#first_your-pagerID span").addClass("ui-icon-newicon");

// Prev page: <
$("#prev_your-pagerID span").removeClass("ui-icon-seek-prev");
$("#prev_your-pagerID span").addClass("ui-icon-newicon");

// Last page: >|
$("#last_your-pagerID span").removeClass("ui-icon-seek-end");
$("#last_your-pagerID span").addClass("ui-icon-newicon");

// Next page: >
$("#next_your-pagerID span").removeClass("ui-icon-seek-next");
$("#next_your-pagerID span").addClass("ui-icon-newicon");
```

Change `your-pagerID` to the ID of your pager.

Change `ui-icon-newicon` to the class of your new icon from the UI icons file (ui-icons_888888_256x240.png)

Comment: I was referring to the forward and back icons in the pager.  I'll revise my original post.

Comment: I couldn't get your answer to work as is, so I tried to incorporate some of the solution in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862963/jqgrid-pager-area-using-font-awesome-icons?rq=1  I've updated my original question above.  Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?