# How can I use font-awesome icon with paramquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, font-awesome

I am using [paramquery](http://paramquery.com/api) to generate grid table, I have added two button inside grid using below code. In this code its using jQuery ui icon now I want to change the icon with font-awesome. Is there any way to get that done ? Thank you in advance for help.

```
                var toolb = $('#grid_generic2').pqGrid("option","toolbar");    
                toolb.items.push({
                    type: 'button', 
                    attr: 'id="addline"', 
                    label: 'Add', 
                    icon: 'ui-icon-plus',  
                    listeners: [{ 
                        click: function(){
                            getPrwNewCase();
                        }
                    }]
                });
                $('#grid_generic2').pqGrid("option","toolbar",toolb);

                var toolb = $('#grid_generic2').pqGrid("option","toolbar");    
                toolb.items.push({
                    type: 'button', 
                    attr: 'id="removeline"', 
                    label: 'Delete', 
                    icon: 'ui-icon-minus',  
                    listeners: [{ 
                        click: function(){
                            delRow();
                        }
                    }]
                });
                $('#grid_generic2').pqGrid("option","toolbar",toolb);
```

Comment: Cant you rewrite it as .jqGrid("initFontAwesome").jqGrid ?? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/1029506

Comment: @ManishJangir it is not jqgrid its [ParamQueryGrid](http://paramquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is stuck with this issue, in my case I was able to solve this by removing the "font-family: inherit" at the beginning of pqgrid.ui.css (or pqgrid.ui.min.css). For some reason it was overwriting font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"