# How increase forward and prev icon in jqgrid using fontawesome?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using FontAwesome icons. It is increasing the other icons but not forward and backward icons. I have included font-awesome.css, fontAwesome4.css, fontAwesome4.js. This is my code:

```js
var $prowed1 = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").find(".ui-pg-table");

$prowed1.find(".ui-pg-button > span.ui-icon-seek-first")
  .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-first")
  .addClass("icon-step-backward");

$prowed1.find(".ui-pg-button > span.ui-icon-seek-prev")
  .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-prev")
  .addClass("icon-backward");

$prowed1.find(".ui-pg-button > span.ui-icon-seek-next")
  .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next")
  .addClass("icon-forward");

$prowed1.find(".ui-pg-button > span.ui-icon-seek-end")
  .removeClass("ui-icon ui-icon-seek-end")
  .addClass("icon-step-forward");
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-titlebar {
  height: 35px !important;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  padding: 10px 2px 1px 2px !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid {
  border: 0px solid !important;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hbox {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

Still not working.Rest of the code for grid is same as the how we write it in normal jqgrid .There is only problem with forward and prev icon.

Comment: Could you be a little more clear about what it is you're trying to do, as the question make very little sense

Comment: The question has no sense if you don't specify the context. Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS]() or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Which `fontAwesome4.css`,`fontAwesome4.js` files you mean? I posed `jQuery.jqGrid.fontAwesome4.js` and `jQuery.jqGrid.fontAwesome4.css` [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins) many years ago after posting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/315935) for retro version of jqGrid: 4.6.0. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) don't need that.

Comment: Jqgrid 5.2 version

Comment: Font size of edit,add,save increased but forward and previous icon remains the same like default jqgrid

Comment: If you use jqGrid version 5.2 I highly recommend you to read first the documentation - especially   the part of [CSS Frameworks guide](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#css-framework-guide)