# Jqgrid: viewGridRow property is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am working in the Concrete5 CMS and I use the jquery jqGrid 4.5.4 version.  I have problem while using the jqgrid in view form.

1. First the label and data are collapsed
2. Description is show long line, and I want to split in multiple lines based on the width (I want like [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappingInViewForm_.htm) demo)
3. How to set the width of the `viewGridRow`?

Some properties are not working in the jqGrid, like `closeOnEscape`, `checkOnSubmit` and `checkOnUpdate`

[image]

My code:

```
var grid = $("#projectGrid");
    var pages = <?php echo json_encode($pl) ?>;
    var emptyMsgDiv = $('<div>No Records.</div>');
    grid.jqGrid({
        caption:'Project List',
        datatype:'local',
        data:pages,
        mtype:'POST',
        colNames:['ID','Project Name','Assignment Name','Client','Start Dt.','Submission Dt.','Description'], 
        colModel:[ 
            {name:'proj_id', key:true, hidden:true}, 
            {name:'proj_name', width:200, sorttype:'text'}, 
            {name:'emp_name', width:200, edittype:'custom', editoptions:{custom_element:function(value, options) { return combobox_element(value, options,'emp_name') }, custom_value:combobox_value }},
            //{name:'c_company_name',width: 100},
            {name:'c_company_name', width: 100, align: "center", formatter: "select", editable: true,
                        edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: dataCli}},
            {name:'proj_start_dt', width:150, sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-Y' }, 
                datefmt: 'd-m-Y', editoptions: { dataInit: initDateStart }, oneditfunc: function() {alert ("edited");},  
                searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
            {name:'proj_end_dt',width:150, sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-Y' }, 
                datefmt: 'd-m-Y', editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEnd }, 
                searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'], dataInit: initDateSearch } }, 
            {name:'proj_description', hidden:true, editrules:{edithidden:true}, edittype:'textarea', search: false  }],
        cmTemplate:{editable:true, editrules: {required:true}}, 
        emptyrecords: 'No records.',
        beforeRequest: function () {if (pages.length === 0) {grid[0].p.page = 0;}},  // fix the page number from 1 to 0 in case of no data  
        loadComplete: function () { var count = grid.getGridParam(); var ts = grid[0]; if (ts.p.reccount === 0) { grid.hide();  emptyMsgDiv.show(); } else { grid.show(); emptyMsgDiv.hide(); } },  
        width:777,      
        height:'auto',
        pager:'#projectPager',
        sortname: 'proj_id',
        sortorder:'asc',
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        rownumbers:true,
        viewrecords:true,
        gridview:true,
        autoencode:true,
        loadonce:true,
        editurl:'<?php echo $this->action('deleteProject'); ?>',
        reloadAfterSubmit: true
        
    });
    
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#projectPager', {
            add:false, edit:true, view: true, del:true, search:true, refresh:true,
            editfunc: function(id){ window.location = 'editProject?pID=' + id;$("#div").html(id);}},    
            {jqModal: true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterEdit: true},
            {jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true, labelswidth: '100%', width: '600' },
            {jqModal: true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape: true},
            {jqModal: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, overlay: true, recreateFilter: true }
        );
    emptyMsgDiv.insertAfter(grid.parent());
    //$("#projectGrid")[0].refreshIndex();
    $("#projectGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

And one more request is Please review my code if any bad or wrong. suggest me how to do better than this. thank you for who help this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options of the View are described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties1). It has no `checkOnSubmit`, `checkOnUpdate` options. The options exist in Add and Edit form, but not in View form. The default value of `closeOnEscape` is false. You should specify `closeOnEscape: true` if required.

It seems to me that to solve your main problem you need just set `width` and `labelswidth` options of View. You need add one more parameter of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) (after the options of Searching dialog).

**UPDATED**:

```
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#projectPager', {
    add:false, edit:true, view: true, del:true, search:true, refresh:true,
    editfunc: function(id){ window.location = 'editProject?pID=' + id;$("#div").html(id);}}, 
    // below are Edit options (prmEdit in the documentation)
    {jqModal: true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterEdit: true},
    // below are Add options (prmAdd in the documentation)
    {jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true},
    // below are Delete options (prmDel in the documentation)
    {jqModal: true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape: true},
    // below are Search options (prmSearch in the documentation)
    {jqModal: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, overlay: true, recreateFilter: true},
    // below are View options (prmView in the documentation)
    {jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true, labelswidth: '35%', width: 600}
);
```

**UPDATED 2**: The option `closeOnEscape: true` works only if the focus is set inside of View dialog. To make the code compatible with the current version of jQuery (to the current implementation of `jQuery.focus()`) one need set `tabindex` attribute on the "Close" button from the title of the View dialog. The View option could be used like below

```
{
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        $form.find("td.DataTD").each(function () {
            var html = $(this).html().trim();  // &nbsp;<span>&nbsp;</span>
            if (html.substr(0, 6) === "&nbsp;" && html.trim().length > 6) {
                $(this).html(html.substr(6));
            }
        });
        $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").find(".ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").attr("tabindex", "-1");
    },
    recreateForm: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    labelswidth: '35%',
    width: 600
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FocusInView.htm) demonstrates the above code.

**UPDATED 3:** By the way I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/two-small-bugs/#p30374) to trirand and Tony already fixed the code of jqGrid from github (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/4a4f36924ec8ff8a37a6cb8b2478a4f994bc1290)). So the next version of jqGrid will don't have the problem with `closeOnEscape: true`.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand the navGrid(after the options of Searching dialog). change the view and search order

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: You confused Delete and View prameters of `navGrid`. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Yeah i got but description value is scrolled (i want like this demo notes in warning row http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/WrappingInViewForm_.htm) and closeOnEscape is not working

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: see the demo from **UPDATED 2** part of my answer.

Comment: One small request will u see this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/22350114/2806972 I cant to find bug in this.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: The post don't have any code which could be debugged. If you provide the URL for the demo which uses `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` then I could post my comments.

Comment: Ok i can understand I am using the jquery.jqgrid.min.js in my all jqgrid.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: I mean just that a picture can't be used to find **the origin** of the problem. One have to debug the problem. About the usage of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`: one uses typically `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` during development and uses `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in the final solution. One need at least temporary replace `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` to be able to debug jqGrid code.

Comment: this origin is when I submit the editform have to {jqModal: true, viewPagerButtons: true, checkOnUpdate:true, savekey: [true,13], navkeys: [false,38,40], checkOnSubmit : true, reloadAfterSubmit:false, closeOnEscape:true, closeAfterEdit: true,width:600, height:300} the dialog box show empty (Not show any icon Yes, No, Cancel)...

Comment: I try to use both jquery.jqGrid.min.js and jquery.jqGrid.src.js ... No use

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50015/discussion-between-kumar-shanmugam-and-oleg)

Comment: Hi @Oleg If i want write this function(Updated2) like closeOnEscape in the jquery.jqgrid.min.js file. Where should I wrote this function. If you give the hint it very useful to me.. Thank you for all the comments and Your answer also.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: It's options of View options of `navGrid`. which you should use instead of `{jqModal: true, closeOnEscape: true, labelswidth: '35%', width: 600}` from the **UPDATE** part of my answer.

Comment: Oh i am nee bee in the jqGrid I don't know this is the bug. Anyway the Delete options of 'navGrid' 'closeOnEscape: true' also not work, so fix t this also in the next version thank you.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: It's do a bug. I posted [the comment](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/4a4f36924ec8ff8a37a6cb8b2478a4f994bc1290#commitcomment-5727575) and I hope that the code of Delete will be also fixed.

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: Tony confirmed that it's a bug an have fixed it in the main code of jqGrid (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/01ccd711cdcdf1870b07f763058e55085c985478)). Thank you for it!

Comment: Hi @Oleg I got this error "$ is not defined" while i am using "jquery.jqGrid.src.js" or "jquery.jqGrid.min.js"... how to clear this error :) I am working in concrete cms, php and mvc pattern.. I got some int from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2195167 but i dnt know how to solve this

Comment: @KumarShanmugam: the error "$ is not defined" means that you either don't included jQuery.js **before** `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or if you included wrong or multiple versions of jQuery.